# Multidimensional session array printing the elements by using echo function

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, echo

I have piece of code that I need to use echo function in order to print the variables inside the session array, on the other hand I need to add prices one by one every time user chooses a product. The prices variable is a string. The code as follows:

```
    if (!is_array($_SESSION['products']['names'])){

      $_SESSION['products']['names']['name'] = array();
      $_SESSION['products']['names']['prices']= array();

      }else {

     $pros = $_SESSION['products']['names']['name'];

     if (in_array($product->getName(), $pros, true)){

         echo 'The product is available in your basket';

} else {

 $prozuct = array_push($_SESSION['products']['names']['name'],$product->getName());
                          array_push($_SESSION['products']['names']['prices'], $product->getPrice(Currency::getCurrentCurrency()));

     foreach ($_SESSION['products'] as  $id=>$arr){

     for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){

      echo $arr['name'][$i];

       }                             
  }

 }   
}
```

The error that I receive is:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Users

And additionally I know that I can use print_r but in my case I want to add prices one by one and calculate and show the total of amount to user.

Comment: Whats going on with the first three lines??

Comment: it is a ajax request call

Comment: I am pleased you found your solution. Just a quick note though - we tend to discourage 'please help' and 'urgent' requests here - (un)fortunately, your question is not more important than the others. Please don't add this to questions - thanks!

Comment: It was urgent for me, I am sorry though if i have made a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a loop:

```
$namesHtml = implode("<br>", $_SESSION['products']['names']['name']);
$total = array_sum($_SESSION['products']['names']['price']);
echo sprintf("<p>Products: <br>%s<br>Total Cost: %s", $namesHtml, $total);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply and help... Perfect Solution